# Object Error: This Key is already associated with an element of this collection

Tags: ms-access, object, vb6, vba

**Explanation:**
I looked up already some answers to this question, but they don´t suite my case.
I am trying to Write a solution for Hex To Binary conversion in VBA, but I get an error mentioned in the title. While I cannot find any other Key that is associated with this element in this collection.

**My CODE:**

```
Public Function HEX2BIN(strHex As String) As String
    Dim oHexValues As Object
    Dim valueBin As String
    Dim l_strHex As Integer
    Set oHexValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


    oHexValues.Add 1, "0001"
    oHexValues.Add 2, "0010"
    oHexValues.Add 3, "0011"
    oHexValues.Add 4, "0100"
    oHexValues.Add 5, "1010"
    oHexValues.Add 6, "0110"
    oHexValues.Add 7, "0111"
    oHexValues.Add 8, "1000"
    oHexValues.Add 9, "1001"
    oHexValues.Add A, "1010"
    oHexValues.Add B, "1011"
    oHexValues.Add C, "1100"
    oHexValues.Add D, "1101"
    oHexValues.Add E, "1110"
    oHexValues.Add F, "1111"

valueBin = ""
l_strHex = Len(strHex)

For i = 1 To l_strHex
    charHex = Mid(strHex, i, 1)
    MsgBox "Chars:" & charHex
    If oHexValues.Exists(charHex) Then
        valueBin = valueBin & oHexValues(charHex)
    ElseIf charHex = "0" Then
        valueBin = valueBin & "0000"
    Else
        MsgBox "Invalid value!"
    End If
Next i
HEX2BIN = valueBin

End Function
```

**ERROR:** *This Key is already associated with an element of this collection*. And the debugger points to the entry:

```
oHexValues.Add B, "1011"
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: That works! Stupid mistake. In my case, if I do the adding with "A", the IF statement won´t recognize the same letter.
For example `oHexValues.Exists(A) != oHexValues.Exists("A")`

But I´ll just wrap the `""` around my charHex. Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like you are not using `Option Explicit`. If you were, then the compiler would have told you that there was no variable named `A`, `B`, ... and you would have caught the problem faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean to add a `String` `"A"` rather than a variable named `A` ? Wrap the letters with quotes like

`oHexValues.Add "A", "1010"`

Comment: It removed the error. But now it says that `oHexValues.Exists("4")` is **FALSE**. Which can´t be true, since I added "4" to my Dictionary.

Comment: Did you add `"4"` or `4`?

Comment: `oHexValues.Add "4", "0100"`

What I want to do is, that when I get "4" in charHex - I´d like to replace it with it´s binary match, which is the pair of `"4"` in my object -> `"0100"`

Comment: Oh gosh..is it the other way around??  Object.Add value, Key ?

Comment: Ok, I think your original problem should now be solved so maybe consider marking this as solved and asking a new question if you have a new one.

Comment: It's `dictionary.add (Key, Item)`